# Question about Ubuntu 12.10 extracting a .tgz file in the wrong directory

Tags: filesystem

I installed the Ubuntu 12.04 then I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10 (the version along with Window 7) When I was using Ubuntu 12.04, I typed `ls` to show what file are listed in directory(included arm-linux-gcc-4.5.1-v6-vfp-20120301.tgz) And the list show out the file that are needed to be extracted. And that i type `sudo tar -zxvf arm-linux-gcc-4.5.1-v6-vfp-20120301.tgz -C /` and file was extracted in the same directory with zip file and own by user. After i install Ubuntu 12.10 redo the processes

1. `ls` (check file again)
2. `sudo tar -zxvf arm-linux-gcc-4.5.1-v6-vfp-20120301.tgz -C /`
   and the extracted  file was in the File System and owned by root and adminstrator can't use it.

What's wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you *wanted* to accomplish here, but you told your computer to do exactly that.

running a program via sudo executes it in the context of the root user, all files created in that process will normally belong to root. The `-C /` parameter of tar, tells tar to extract to the / Directory, you actually need root permissions to do that at all.

If you just want to unroll the file contents into your home directory, simply run
`tar -zxvf arm-linux-gcc-4.5.1-v6-vfp-20120301.tgz`, you may want to make sure, you *are* in your home directory first by enterin `cd ~`.

You might want to consider using a graphical program like xarchiver for unzipping, depending on what you demand of yourself (maybe ou want to become a command line crack, this would be a honourable goal ;-).

Comment: Out of curiosity... why are you unpacking a C compiler runnable on arm architecture?